# JQuery Delay not Working

Tags: jquery

I want #load to show (while hiding #body) then hide #load, and make #body visible with a fadein. Thats what I ultimately want. I don't think the ajaxstart and stop is the way to do. It is just a splash screen.

basically hide #body on page load, show #load for a few seconds, then hide it, then show #body again. How come nobody can figure this out!

jsfiddle.net/peTSQ

```
var body = $( '#body' );

$( body ).hide();
$( this ).show().delay( 3000 ).hide( 0, function () {
   $( body ).show(); 
});
```

Comment: The best way of doing this sort of thing is using the "success" parameter on the $.ajax function. You can then stop the "loading" stuff when the ajax request gets an answer. I think your mis-intepreting ajaxStart and ajaxStop

Comment: what does the AJAX call on #load do exactly. Maybe it is swapping out the content before the show fires?

Comment: `'none'` - good name for a class `:P`

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally overwrote your question. I'm trying to roll-back, but I can't figure out how...

Comment: @Sime, fixed. Ill forgive you if you help me!

Comment: @JD Ah yes, I had to click on my name to get to the rollback options... totally forgot that.

Comment: @Sime, no. http://jsfiddle.net/peTSQ/

Comment: @Sime, I want to hide the #load div after the #body.

Comment: @JDAudi My code shows the #load element for 3 seconds, then hides it and shows the #body element. That's not what you want?

Comment: @Sime, it does not.. Look http://jsfiddle.net/peTSQ/2/

Comment: @JDAudi That's because my code "assumes" that `this` refers to the #load element. If you want to make it work in jsFiddle, you have to establish both references. **Proper demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/peTSQ/4/

Comment: @Sime, got it. Yes yours works. But my simple site does not. It just loads everything all at once.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
var body = $( '#body' );

$( body ).hide();
$( this ).show().delay( 3000 ).hide( 0, function () {
   $( body ).show(); 
});
```

Comment: @ŠimeVidas nope. I want #load to show (while hiding #body) then hide #load, and make #body visible with a fadein. Thats what I ultimately want. I don't think the ajaxstart and stop is the way to do. It is just a splash screen.

Comment: @JDAudi OK, how is the class `'none'` related to this?

Comment: @the class is removed. I just used that to make the #body not show until i removed the class with query. You don't have to use it. all it is is display:none. I just want the above functionality

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you want to have your delay, you may or may not be close.  In addition, you can utilize a simple setTimeout() function to display your desired item for only a certain amount of time as well.

The following will show it for 600 ms and then hide the item:

```
$("#load").show().delay(600).hide();
```

Per the jQuery documentation, the purpose of the delay() function:

> Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

As a result, you may just want to use setTimeout since you are not separating any events, but are instead just creating a delay:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#load").show(); }, 600);
```

Comment: How would I incorporate that into my script as it is?

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```
$("#load").fadeOut("slow", function() { $("body").fadeIn('slow'); });
```

Comment: How would I incorporate that into my script as it is?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it should work. Are you just trying to create an overlay when during ajax calls?

Comment: You might check this plugin out, I use this in several of my projects: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Comment: I just want to show the #load for a few seconds then show #body

Comment: I would suggest keeping it simple as shown above at first, then trying to add more functionality. You might just leverage an existing plugin as the one I suggest earlier (http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) which gives specific examples on how to make this work.

Comment: nope. I want #load to show (while hiding #body) then hide #load, and make #body visible with a fadein. Thats what I ultimately want. I don't think the ajaxstart and stop is the way to do. It is just a splash screen.

Comment: Doesn't work. I want to show #load for a few seconds, fade out, then fade in #body. This doesn't even let the #load show.

Comment: Well you will need to adjust your css to make this work. #load should be visible, #body or whatever container you want to appear will need to be display: none at page load. Then this should work. You need to figure out your default state and code around it. Without seeing the underlying HTML/CSS we're all just guessing here.